# Symfony2 on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Configure config.yml

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run an app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, this app is programmed in Symfony2 and is able to run in any normal server, however I want to use it in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

Until now I have uploaded the code using git(thanks to the tutorial: http://vincent.composieux.fr/article/deploy-a-symfony-project-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk),

Then I also connected to the server using SSH.

But now I want to configurate the symfony2 app parameters inside parameters.yml, but I cannot find the root location of the app in the server, does anybody know where Amazon stores source code of such an web-app?

Under /var/www/html I couldn't find anything :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the location myself /var/app/ondeck

thanks to http://vincent.composieux.fr/article/deploy-a-symfony-project-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk